# MySql Joins and the Data after a query

Tags: mysql

I am confused about joins and join queries for mysql. After i do a join, is there data returned to the callback function, just like how data is returned after doing a SELECT * query? If so, does the data that is returned from the join query have data from the columns in both tables? Example, if table users has a column name and a table posts has column posts, does the data returned after the join have access to both columns. Such as data.name and data.posts?

Comment: If you use joins in a select query, then it will remain a select query. Data returned by the query is determined by the query itself.

Comment: It seems that there's a bit of confusion about how the data is fetched using `JOIN`s. `SELECT u.name, p.posts FROM users AS u JOIN posts AS p ON u.user_id = p.user_id`. It's a good practice to prefix column names in `SELECT` by the table name or its alias (`u` and `p` here). If speaking of the query itself, then only the columns that you specifically include in `SELECT` will be accessible (displayable).  From a programming language's perspective, the whole result set is returned to it, and therefore any columns included in `SELECT` can be accessed by variables. For example, PHP: `$data['col']`

Answer (score 2):

Yes, a join is like taking a row from one table and putting it side-by-side with a matching row from another table. The result is a wider set of columns, some columns from the first table and some from the second table.

The result of a join is like a table itself, in that it has columns and the columns have names and data types.

It's also like a table in that you can use it to join to yet another table.

That's really the innovative thing that was so exciting when relational databases were invented in 1970. Every operation you can do in a query makes a result set that you can use in a further operation, as if it were a table. So you can keep building more powerful queries.

Think of arithmetic.

```
2 + 2 = 4
```

These are two integers, that you add together and it returns *another integer*. And you can use any integer, even one that is the result of an arithmetic expression, in yet another arithmetic operation.

```
4 + 3  = 7
```

So in relational databases, you can do several things that produce results:

- *Projection*, naming a subset of specific columns.
- *Selection*, applying a condition to find a subset of rows that match the condition.
- *Rename*, giving columns in the result set different names than the columns in the tables they came from.
- *Join*, matching rows from one table to rows of another table.
- *Aggregation*, doing something with a group of rows, like counting the rows, finding the sum total of a column, finding the min or max value in a column.

And just like in arithmetic, you can build up complex combinations of these operations.